# Writing variable value to xml file from xsl code

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there is an easy way to read a value from external xml file to a variable?

```
<xsl:variable name="varName" select="document('docName.xml')"/>
```

My requirement is just reverse i.e. to write the variable value to an
external xml file so that the variable value can be read from external
xml file when required.

I want the external xml file containing the variable value to get created whenever an xml file having a href to some xsl is run in the browser.   I don’t want to create it by "Run as XSLT transformation" in eclipse.   I've already used the following piece of code to do the same.

**book.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="writeVar.xsl" ?> 
<books>
    <book>      
        <bookName>JAVA For Beginners</bookName>         
        <author>Balagurusamy</author>       
        <edition>2nd</edition>      
        <publicationDate>16 July 2008</publicationDate>         
        <price>INR 350.00</price>       
        <type>E</type>  
    </book>

    <book>      
        <bookName>XSLT</bookName>
        <author>Amit Roy</author>       
        <edition>3rd</edition>      
        <publicationDate>16 July 2008</publicationDate>         
        <price>INR 350.00</price>       
        <type>O</type>  
    </book>      
</books>
```

In **writeVar.xsl** I've a variable named javaBook. I want to write
the   value of this variable to external xml file say output.xml
whenever **book.xml    is run in the browser.**

I've tried using `xsl:result-document` but the output.xml is not getting created when I run book.xml in the browser.

Please suggest how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have several questions here. You start asking about input, then switch to asking about output. For the former you almost answered yourself -- if you want a specific value from the other document, follow the document() call with additional xpath steps to extract the value you're looking for. For the latter, I suspect you're running into browser security issues.

Comment: Hi Keshlam, I'm sorry perhaps I could not explain it properly. The question is very straight forward is there a way to write a variable value from xsl to external xml file,if Yes, how?

Comment: I presume you mean "other than the XSLT's output document." In XSLT 1.0, the answer is "not unless your processor provides an extension for that purpose." In XSLT 2.0, the `xsl:result-document` instruction allows creating multiple output documents, and you could use that mechanism. All of the preceding assumes that you are not running in a "sandbox" environment which prevents writing to files.

Comment: Hi keshlam, I've tried using  xsl:result-document but the file to which the output should be written is not getting created when I run the xml having reference to some xsl file in the browser. The code is like this          
    
<xsl:result-document href="preface.xml" method="xml">
<xsl:value-of select="$java"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:result-document>                                            I've used xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"                                Here I believe that preface.xml should get created and contain value of variable java.

Comment: Few browsers supported 2.0, last I looked. And a browser is the classic sandbox environment; I would expect writing to local files to be blocked except for signed code that has been explicitly approved by the users to do so, and even then may be restricted. Never mind the specific of writing an XML file -- what problem are you really trying to solve that cookies, or a user-initiated download/save, don't address?

Comment: I wanted to write response sent by a web service to some xml file so that when the service is down i can read the last response from the local xml file and hence the app works fine even when the service is down.